# Where do I log bugs and ask for help for libguestfs on ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'd like  t o know   where to get help  using libguestfs on ubuntu. The libguestfs project page is hosted by  redhat.

I'm trying to use guestfish on  a  qemu VM. I can initiate  the  CLI console but  trying to run , fails.

My code is

```
export LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1
export LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1

set -x

WORKSPACE='tmp'
TARGETDIR='tmp'

guestfish <<_EOF_
  add ${WORKSPACE}/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
  run
_EOF_

set +x
```

The error message I  get  is

```
> root@ubuntu:/tmp# ./test.sh 
> ++ WORKSPACE=tmp
> ++ TARGETDIR=tmp
> ++ guestfish libguestfs: trace: set_verbose true libguestfs: trace: set_verbose = 0 libguestfs: create: flags = 0, handle = 0x10d1830,
> program = guestfish libguestfs: trace: add_drive
> "tmp/trusty-amd64-42G.img" libguestfs: trace: add_drive = 0
> libguestfs: trace: launch libguestfs: trace: get_tmpdir libguestfs:
> trace: get_tmpdir = "/tmp" libguestfs: trace: version libguestfs:
> trace: version = <struct guestfs_version *> libguestfs: trace:
> get_backend libguestfs: trace: get_backend = "direct" libguestfs:
> launch: program=guestfish libguestfs: launch: version=1.24.5
> libguestfs: launch: backend registered: unix libguestfs: launch:
> backend registered: uml libguestfs: launch: backend registered:
> libvirt libguestfs: launch: backend registered: direct libguestfs:
> launch: backend=direct libguestfs: launch:
> tmpdir=/tmp/libguestfsoj7MG8 libguestfs: launch: umask=0022
> libguestfs: launch: euid=0 libguestfs: command: run:
> /usr/bin/supermin-helper libguestfs: command: run: \ --verbose
> libguestfs: command: run: \ -f checksum libguestfs: command: run: \
> --host-cpu x86_64 libguestfs: command: run: \ /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d supermin helper [00000ms] whitelist = (not
> specified) supermin helper [00000ms] host_cpu = x86_64 supermin helper
> [00000ms] dtb_wildcard = (not specified) supermin helper [00000ms]
> inputs: supermin helper [00000ms] inputs[0] =
> /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d supermin helper [00000ms] outputs:
> supermin helper [00000ms] kernel = (none) supermin helper [00000ms]
> dtb = (none) supermin helper [00000ms] initrd = (none) supermin helper
> [00000ms] appliance = (none) checking modpath
> /lib/modules/3.13.0-66-generic is a directory picked kernel
> vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic supermin helper [00000ms] finished creating
> kernel supermin helper [00000ms] visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d
> supermin helper [00000ms] visiting
> /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/daemon.img.gz supermin helper [00000ms]
> visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/init.img supermin helper
> [00000ms] visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/udev-rules.img supermin
> helper [00000ms] adding kernel modules supermin helper [00013ms]
> finished creating appliance libguestfs: checksum of existing
> appliance:
> d00a2496c32876d41bfc78987c43add8c1c0f0c6f16233bec9d9069e23a57e38
> libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir =
> "/var/tmp" libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir libguestfs: trace:
> get_cachedir = "/var/tmp" libguestfs: [00019ms] begin building
> supermin appliance libguestfs: [00020ms] run supermin-helper
> libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/supermin-helper libguestfs:
> command: run: \ --verbose libguestfs: command: run: \ --copy-kernel
> libguestfs: command: run: \ -f ext2 libguestfs: command: run: \
> --host-cpu x86_64 libguestfs: command: run: \ /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d libguestfs: command: run: \
> --output-kernel /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q/kernel libguestfs: command: run: \ --output-initrd /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q/initrd libguestfs:
> command: run: \ --output-appliance /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q/root
> supermin helper [00000ms] whitelist = (not specified) supermin helper
> [00000ms] host_cpu = x86_64 supermin helper [00000ms] dtb_wildcard =
> (not specified) supermin helper [00000ms] inputs: supermin helper
> [00000ms] inputs[0] = /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d supermin helper
> [00000ms] outputs: supermin helper [00000ms] kernel =
> /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q/kernel supermin helper [00000ms] dtb = (none)
> supermin helper [00000ms] initrd = /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q/initrd
> supermin helper [00000ms] appliance = /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q/root
> checking modpath /lib/modules/3.13.0-66-generic is a directory picked
> kernel vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic supermin helper [00013ms] finished
> creating kernel supermin helper [01371ms] finished mke2fs supermin
> helper [01372ms] visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d supermin helper
> [01372ms] visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/daemon.img.gz supermin
> helper [01410ms] visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/init.img
> supermin helper [01410ms] visiting
> /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/udev-rules.img /usr/bin/supermin-helper:
> ext2: parent directory not found: /lib: File not found by ext2_lookup
> *stdin*:2: libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin-helper exited with error status 1, see debug messages above libguestfs: command: run: rm
> libguestfs: command: run: \ -rf /var/tmp/guestfs.Jwej9Q libguestfs:
> trace: launch = -1 (error) libguestfs: trace: close libguestfs:
> closing guestfs handle 0x10d1830 (state 0) libguestfs: command: run:
> rm libguestfs: command: run: \ -rf /tmp/libguestfsoj7MG8
> ++ set +x
```

It appears that the important part is:

```
supermin helper [01410ms] visiting /usr/lib/guestfs/supermin.d/udev-rules.img
/usr/bin/supermin-helper: ext2: parent directory not found: /lib: File not found by ext2_lookup
*stdin*:2: libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin-helper exited with error status 1, see debug messages above
```

How can I  begin understanding what  is  happening here? My  hunch is  that  the guest VM (trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img_ on which I  am running Guestfish (to instantiate another trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img)  lacks something needed for  virtualisation. KVM acceleration  is not enabled  but  I assume  its something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post on the [mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/libguestfs) — there's no need to subscribe.  This particular issue is likely caused because you need to run:

```
sudo update-guestfs-appliance
```

(see [the FAQ entry here](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#libguestfs:-error:-cannot-find-any-suitable-libguestfs-supermin-fixed-or-old-style-appliance-on-libguestfs_path)).